# C# MVC view template engine for print previews

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am searching for MVC view template engines which can be stored in database and used for print previews.

I want to generate generic view, save it into database and then show it as popup (print preview)

But I don't know which view engine is good for this? I am looking noew `freemarker`. Is it ok?

Or just replace all data objects in C# with database?

Comment: Have you considered using a print stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would create a style sheet especially for printouts.
This can be done by using the @print CSS Media Type:

```
@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

You can change the width, orientation etc of everything in your page, you could even use the `display:'none'` feature to hide certain parts of the page.

If you build out your screens with razor and this css stylesheet referenced to it you'll be able to use variables with razor and build out the CSS stylesheet to create the view that you want for printing purposes.

Check these resources to get you started:
[W3 Schools: CSS print](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)
[HowTo from Webcredible](http://www.webcredible.com/blog-reports/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)